# Reference a class library only if it exists - .NET Core

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, api-design

I have an API that has it's controllers in a separate class library. Currently this library is referenced as a project from the main\core API project. This API is deployed to the customers site, so each customer has their own setup. Sometimes we are required to add an API call that is specific to one company. I do not want to put it in the main controller library, because it is really important that only the one company can see the specific calls we created for them.

My question is: is it possible to create another controllers library and load it if it exists, but otherwise do not error out if it doesn't exist. That way, if a company needs their own special calls, i would setup the API like normal, but then also just copy their special controllers.dll into the setup also. A setup might look like this.

> **COMPANY 1**
>   core-api-logic.exe
>   shared-controllers.dll
>   *comp1-controllers.dll*
>
> **COMPANY 2**
>   core-api-logic.exe
>   shared-controllers.dll
>   *comp2-subdivision1-controllers.dll*
>   *comp2-subdivision2-controllers.dll*

---

Note: The controller libraries are never manually called from the core logic, they simply exist to house the controllers.

Comment: What do you give each client, binaries or binaries and code?

Comment: We distribute just the binaries. Currently as self-contained to IIS using the .net core web hosting bundle.

Comment: I would add a general/dummy library and add an if to IoC code which decides general/dummy library will be loaded avoiding error or client specific, real implementation. Please, see [autofac](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) documentation.

Comment: This is how "assembly-based plugins" (keywords!) work: the plugins are *not* directly referenced in any project, but are rather loaded at run-time. During development the projects (and even solutions) are separate. There may be common interfaces used to assist with loading, eg.

Comment: Do you want to achieve something [OSGi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) can provide you?